# RS-232 signal inverter

Tags: arduino, serial, rs232

I need some advice concerning the building of a signal inverter for an [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) connection. I'm using a [MAX3323](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/transceivers/MAX3323E.html) to convert a serial tx/rx of an Arduino to RS-232 standard. The point is that I'm not able to use dual power supply, and the MAX is inverting, in this way I end up with a signal having only a negative voltage range. A normal computer is able to interpret the string I'm sending, but the machine I have to command does not do that. I think this is because it requires signal having a positive dynamic, hence I need to invert it. Can you give me any suggestion about the circuit to build?

Comment: If the device you want the Arduino to communicate with uses "TTL level" serial communications, you shouldn't need the MAX3323. (The MAX3323 internally creates the negative supply, and its outputs will swing both positive and negative.)

Comment: Have you bothered to check (use voltmeter) the transmitter output voltages? Easy to test. Glancing at the datasheet I see that this range for the transmitter, namely \$-5\:\textrm{V}\lt V_O \lt +5\:\textrm{V}\$, doesn't happen normally. So you should see values other than within that range. Have you checked?

Comment: TTL serial data always is hi=idle and start bit is low ="0" and conversion to RS232 consists of both conversion to bipolar and logic inversion. at both ends.

Comment: user117043 - (a) "I end up with a signal having only a negative voltage range" - how did you measure the signal to decide that? (b) "A normal computer is able to interpret the string I'm sending" - do you mean a PC with RS-232 interface? (c) How did you conclude the computer (PC?) could "interpret the string"? (d) "the machine I have to command does not do that" - what is that machine? Please supply link to more details. (e) Why do you believe the problem is related to the RS-232 voltage levels, and not something else? (f) "it requires signal having a positive dynamic" - give evidence, please.

Comment: I used a computer having a RS232 interface and i noticed the computer could interpret the string since i programmed the arduino to print a sequence of characters and i was able to read them on a serial monitor in the PC.  The machine is a Leica EM PACT 2, and is an high pressure freezer that can be activated by sending a certain string. I believe it is in the voltage levels because if i analyze the signal with a logic analyzer, to interpret it i must say to invert the level not to have "framing error". I think the PC with the build int interface does it automatically, the Leica doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see answers to my questions (a) & (f), and limited info to (d) and (e). Based on your reply, I suspect an *XY problem* situation and your real problem is likely not your guess at needing inversion of the RS-232 signals. I searched for info on that Leica device, but could only find info on its basic operation - nothing on its RS-232 interface. That lack of info prevents me checking a theory that I have. I suspect your logic analyser (LA) test is viewing the "TTL" UART signals from the Arduino, and on some LAs, it is *normal* for them to need to be inverted. Problem elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of questions (a) & (f)but characters are limited. I looked at the dynamics of my signal using an oscilloscope, and well answer (f) is a guess, because the computer can read the string while the machine cannot. Basically i have no idea why the computer can read the string and the machine doesn't. The machine is a pressurized freezer; if it receives a certain string it starts the freezing process. (e) The only other possibility since the PC reads the string, assuming RS232 has correct voltage levels, is the machine software.

Comment: Concerning the LA, well i connected it directly on the rs232 cable, so it is viewing the signals coming out from the MAX3323

Answer (score 1):

RS-232 signalling, such as the MAX3323 generates, is bipolar, going both
above +3V, and below -3V, when fully loaded.   That MAX3323 chip has onboard generators for its power.   The inversion (positive input yields negative output)
is normal for RS-232 drivers (and receivers, which do a second inversion, at the other end).

If your target machine does not accept the  inverted signal, it is probably
intended for TTL-level drive with no MAX3323 intermediate required (and
won't work well with long connecting cables).   The MAX3323 can be omitted,
if this is the case.

Comment: Actually I can control the machine only via a RS232 plug, and on the manual it is says we are dealing with RS232 standard. If i connect my circuit to a PC with a RS232, and open a serial terminal, i can perfectly read the string which should activate the machine. But connecting it directly to the machine it does not work at all. I used then a Logic analyzer to see what kind of string I am sending, it shows "framing error" unless I set to invert the signal. So i think that i'm reading the string on the PC since the software inverts it, but the machine doesn't, do you think it is reasonable?

Comment: The RS-232 'quiescent' state is HIGH (+3V or higher); if the TXD- pin on the Arduino's RS-232 port connector is HIGH when there is no signal, and if that matches the RS-232 port connector on the PC, then those ports are wired the same, and should both work with a cable that connects their TXD- socket to the RXD- pin on the target machine.   Connecting your circuit to a PC, are you using a null modem cable?  And your circuit to the target machine, what kind of cable is used for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you can receive the string on a PC than polarity of the signal is OK for sure. Maybe the problem is with the cable. Swap connections to pins 2 and 3 at one end of the cable ( Tx / Rx ).

Comment: Yes, this could be it. RS232 has the concept of DTE and DCE - Data Terminal Equipment, and Data Communications Equipment. A lot of words that just mean your RX and TX are swapped between the two types. So your wiring may be set up to talk to DTE, what the computer is, and the machine you are trying to control is DCE. Swap pins 2 and 3, and you may be in business!

Comment: Actually at first i had TX and RX reversely connected, at that point both the computer and the machine couldn't read the string. After swapping the polarity the computer begun to read it but the machine didn't